# Double integral $\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$

I know that i need to switch to polar coordinates. $x^2+y^2$ = $r^2$. But i dont understand how to switch between limits of integration. $x=0$ so $\psi$ = $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (if $x=rcos\psi$ and $y = rsin\psi$). And so on

Comment: In such problems it really helps to draw the domain of integration in xy-coordinates. On the picture you should see the domain in polar coordinates.

Comment: The integral is $$\iint_{\substack{x,y\ge 0\\x^2+y^2\le a^2}} e^{x^2+y^2}\; dx\; dy\ .$$ Where is the problem now? First quadrant in the disc of radius $a>0$ (i suppose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is over a quarter circle area, In polar coordinates, it is the region bounded by,

$$r\le a, \>\>\> 0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Therefore,

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_0^a e^{r^2} r dr d\phi =\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac 12 (e^{a^2}-1) d\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}(e^{a^2}-1)$$

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on the reasoning of how one decides on the limits under a change of variables, if you would be so kind as to indulge me.

Let's take a step back and look at the equation of a circle. A circle, with radius $a$ about the origin, has the equation
$$
x^2 + y^2 = a^2,
$$
which we can rearrange to express the $y$-coordinate as a function of the $x$-coordinate as $y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ (working only with the positive $y$-values to avoid problems of sign). Now, if we let $x$ vary between $0$ and $a$, then the corresponding $y$-coordinate will vary between $a$ and $0$, thus the curve given by the coordinates $(x, y)$ will describe the arc of a circle, radius $a$ about the origin, describing a quarter of its circumference, starting when the $y$-coordinate is zero, and ending when the $y$-coordinate is $a$. (I invite you to draw a picture, as this will be most helpful.)

Now, from the polar point of view, the functions $a\cos(\theta)$ and $a\sin(\theta)$ describe the $x$- and $y$-coordinates, respectively, of a point on the circle of radius $a$ about the origin, at the angle $\theta$ measured from the positive $x$-axis. The $x$ value should vary from $0$ to $a$, as we know, and the values of $\theta$ for which this is the case are those for which $0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. We can check that these values for $\theta$ also produce the correct behaviour for the $y$-coordinate; indeed, $y = a\sin(\theta)$ would vary from $0$ (at $\theta = 0$) to $a$ (at $\theta=\pi/2$).

With this knowledge, we can start to construct our change of variables. Our outer integral will describe the variation in the angle $\theta$, from $0$ to $\pi/2$, while the inner integral will describe the variation in the radius $r$, from $0$ to $a$. This is because, in the original double integral, the limits on $y$ are from $0$ to the value of $y$ that lies on the circle, for each $x$. Whence our integral can be expressed as
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^a e^{r^2}r\, dr\,d\theta.
$$
I hope this explains some of the reasoning involved in a little more detail.